# In Windows, opening executables and writing output files quickly is failing randomly

Tags: windows, process

I've got an executable that does some structural analysis. It's compiled from old Fortran code, somewhat of a black box. It reads an input file and writes output to the command window.

I've integrated that executable into an Excel VBA macro to do design optimization. My optimization routine does

1. Write 10 input files in different directories
2. Call 10 concurrent instances of the executable (each of the 10 instances is from a copied and renamed version of the exe file) and pipe the output to a file
3. Wait for them all to finish
4. Read in output files, use the results to generate a new set of designs, and start again.

The executable runs very quickly, less than a second for all the concurrent instances.

This scheme is pretty reliable when I run it on its own. However, I'd like to run multiple optimization jobs concurrently. So imagine 8 or 10 instances of Excel, each running these optimizations concurrently. On my computer, it generally runs fine. On other, nominally identical spec, machines, we're running into problems, where the output file isn't getting created, either because the executable isn't getting called, or is failing to run, or the output is failing to be piped to the results file. I'd welcome suggestions to check for those. This doesn't happen every time, maybe once per 1000 iterations. But it does happen simultaneously across most of the Excel instances and most of the 10 executable calls.

Any idea what is going wrong? It seems like it has something to do with calling so many executables or writing so many files so quickly.

Comment: Do you re-use the same filenames over time? I'm asking because sometimes the filesystem pretends a file is deleted, but actually takes a few seconds (especially if it's very busy) to flush the commands - this can make the next run fail if it assumes the file is writeable whereas it's actually busy.

Comment: I do. I've built in a workaround that, when it detects that an output file is missing, rerun the analysis. This might take enough time for the problem to resolve. It works on my computer on the few times I've run into this, but not always on other computers. Perhaps the solution is to implement a little bit of a delay before rerunning....

Comment: If possible, use different filenames each iteration, e.g., append _n to the filename where n is a counter.